# Session expire redirection on Ajax request in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to redirect or send ajax response about the session expired in YII2.
Currently i am getting `Forbidden(402) Login Required` message as ajax response

Answer (score 1):

you have an action that ajax request sent to it , 
you have to change accessControll to public for that action , to Anonymous access . (input this function in your controller )

```
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
    public function behaviors()
        {
        return [

            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'rules' => [
                     [
                        'actions' => ['view','you-action-name-for-ajax'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        // 'roles' => ['?'],

                    ],
                ],
            ],

        ];
    }
```

be sure to remove to Roles line .. I comment it .